# handle soft delete in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a soft delete for one of my table and for that currently, I am using two SQL queries. 
1. to insert NEW record 
2. to insert deleted records

I was wondering if there is an easy and efficient way to do this in single query

**Employee Table**
This is a target table, which should reflect history

```
Name    Salary  DelInd
Tom     4000    n
Ben     7000    n
Sara    4800    n
Valarie 5500    n
Jaes    6500    n
Russell 8800    n
XXX     9000    y
```

and I have an **EmployeeStaing** Table as mentioned below

```
Name    Salary
Tom     4000
Ben     7000
Sara    4800
Valarie 5500
AAA     2000
BBB     2500
```

To **Insert New Record** I am using following query

```
insert into Employee 
select staging.Name, staging.Gender,staging.Salary, staging.DepartmentID , 'n'
from 
EmployeeStaging as staging 
Left outer join 
(
    select * from Employee 
    where DelInd='n'
) emp
on 
staging.Name = emp.Name
where 
emp.Name is null
```

And to **Insert Deleted Record** I am using following query.

```
insert into Employee
select emp.Name, emp.Gender,emp.Salary, emp.DepartmentID, 'y'
from 
(
    select * from Employee 
    where DelInd='n'
) emp

left outer join EmployeeStaging as staging
on 
emp.Name = staging.Name
where 

staging.Name is null
```

After this my final Table looks like this,

```
Name    Salary  DelInd
Tom     4000    n
Ben     7000    n
Sara    4800    n
Valarie 5500    n
Jaes    6500    n
Russell 8800    n
XXX     9000    Y
AAA     2000    n
BBB     2500    n
Jaes    6500    y
Russell 8800    y
```

Comment: Your two queries look identical (copying error?), but in any case, a soft delete would require an _update_ to a table, to mark it as deleted, and you can't do an update and an insert at the same time.  But you could use a single transaction to do both things.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, it was copying error.  The requirement is not to update the record. but to add a new entry with a timestamp to maintain history. I have not mentioned the timestamp column here, as I think it's not relavant.

Comment: `Insert Deleted Record` does not make sense to me.  Soft deletion typically is implemented by maintaining a boolean column which keeps track of whether a record is logically deleted or not.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `DelInd` column is for that only.